# Why won't the div position update with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to move a div across the screen.  I am currently using jQuery's .css(), but the div remains in the same spot.  Eventually it will be a "bouncing ball" demo, but at the moment the div should only move when clicked.

The HTML:

```
<div id="ball"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#ball {
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#BADA55;  
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xSpeed = 3,
      ySpeed = 2;

  $("#ball").click(function moveIt() {
    var pos = $("#ball").position();
    var maxWidth = $(document).width(),
        maxHeight = $(document).height(),
        x = pos.left,
        y = pos.top;

    x += xSpeed;
    y += ySpeed;

    if(x <= 0 || x+12 >= maxWidth) {
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;   
    }
    if(y <= 0 || y + 12 >= maxHeight) {
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;   
    }

    var yCSS = y + 'px',
        xCSS = x + 'px';

    $("#box").css({top:yCSS, left:xCSS});      
  });
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/6J5P7/).

Additional Info:

-I've attempted the same movement with .animate(), but I didn't have any luck.

-I've also attempted getting the position with .offset(), but no luck there either.

-I know it can be done with HTML5 and the canvas element, as shown [here](http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/), but I would like to stick with jQuery and CSS for this.

-Bonus cool points if anyone can explain why when I try to call it recursively it throws an error (I believe it was max stack exceeded, but if someone wants to attempt it I can change my fiddle to reproduce there error to get the exact error message).

Comment: I have the fiddle set to base, which has been updated since the question was answered.  Just an FYI to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this

```
$("#box").css({top:yCSS, left:xCSS});
```

You are trying to move #box :), should be #ball
http://jsfiddle.net/6J5P7/28/

Comment: 7 minutes until I can accept the answer, but that's what it was.  I upvoted in the mean time.  I've been banging my head against a wall for an hour now, and it was a typo the whole time.  Go figure!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change #box with #ball

```js
$("#ball").css({top:yCSS, left:xCSS});
```